# Is it possible to run Karate test in a pod? If possible, then how?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I just want to know whether I can run Karate test in a pod. Or is there any good suggestion on how to run it?

I tried to run the Karate test in terminal and it works. Just want to know if I can run it from Kubernetes pod. Nginx also running in the pod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can everything in pod whatever you are running outside environment. Pod run the container inside it.

So create the `docker file` and generate the `docker image` using docker file. Using that docker image and start the karate pod.

You can write the docker file like this

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
COPY pom.xml /tmp/pom.xml

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN mvn -B -f /tmp/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml prepare-package -DskipTests

CMD ["/usr/src/app/maven_runner.sh"]
```

I found here one example : https://github.com/neillfontes/karate-sample

Comment: I got this error when I try the example:

[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.callonce:demo:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.intuit.karate:karate-parent:pom:0.3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Try again and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 12

Comment: did you created docker build ?

Comment: I run the docker build -t karate_docker . and that error comes out.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as Community Wiki for future use.

@Harsh Manvar provided good example, however if you will just build it from Dockerfile, you will recieved errors. You have to download all files mentioned in [Github](https://github.com/neillfontes/karate-sample). Correct oreder will be:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/neillfontes/karate-sample.git
$ cd karate-sample
$ docker build -t karate_docker .
```

After image was built you can check it:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
karate_docker       latest              9dc6d7a5278a        About a minute ago   136MB
```

Later you can start testing using:

```
$ docker run karate_docker
START: Running tests...

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running demo.DemoTest
11:57:49.684 [main] DEBUG c.i.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - init test class: class demo.DemoTest
11:57:50.412 [main] DEBUG c.i.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - loading feature: /usr/src/app/target/test-classes/demo/features/get-token.feature
11:57:50.663 [main] DEBUG c.i.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner - loading feature: /usr/src/app/target/test-classes/demo/features/make-request.feature
11:57:53.898 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate.ScriptBridge - karate.env system property was: null
11:57:54.867 [main] DEBUG c.i.k.h.a.RequestLoggingInterceptor -
1 > POST http://brentertainment.com/oauth2/lockdin/token
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 96
```